# Iterate over a multidimensional javascript array and create new array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional JavaScript array with some string data.

```
var array = [];

array[0] = ["A","B","C"];  
array[1] = ["G","H"];
```

I want to merge these together into a new array.

Value 1 from the first array should merge with value 1 from array 2 and so on.

Of course, I can do like this.

```
var array2 = array[0][0] + array[1][0];
```

But I don't the data so the first array could hold 6 values and there could also be more than 2 arrays.

Is there a way to dynamically iterate over the multidimensional array and create a new array.

Comment: `["A","B","C"].concat(["G","H"])`

Comment: var array2 = array[0][0] + array[1][0];                                                               array2 = "AG".

Comment: `array.map(x => x[0])`

Comment: please add the expected output and the code that you had tried

Comment: The output should be "AG".

Comment: `array.map(function(v){ return v[0]; }).join('')`

Comment: *The output should be "AG"* This does not seem consistent with your statement that *Value 1 from first array should merge with value 1 from array 2 and so on*--or what do you mean by "and so on"?

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** methods.

```
// iterate over multi diamensional array and
// generate array with first element of each nested array
var array2 = array.map(function(v){ 
   // retrieve the first element
   return v[0]; 
   // join them to convert into a string as your output
}).join('')
```

```js
var array = [];

array[0] = ["A", "B", "C"];
array[1] = ["G", "H"];

var array2 = array.map(function(v) {
  return v[0];
}).join('')

console.log(array2);
```

---

If you want to do the same with all index then use **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)** method.

```js
var array = [];

array[0] = ["A", "B", "C"];
array[1] = ["G", "H"];

// iterate and reduce a single array
var array2 = array.reduce(function(arr, e) {
  // iterate over nested array 
  e.forEach(function(v, i) {
    // concatenate with the elements in parent array
    arr[i] = (arr[i] || '') + v;
  });
  return arr
  // set initial value as array
}, [])

console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Perfect. This is exactly what i need. You made my day.

Comment: @AlexClaesson : glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The most compact way of writing this would be the following:

```
arrays[0].map((_, i) => arrays.map(array => array[i]).join(''))
```

Breaking it down:

```
arrays[0]                     // Starting with the first sub-array,
  .map(                       // create a corresponding array 
    (_, i) =>                 // whose value, for each index is,
      arrays                  // for each of the sub-arrays,
        .map(                 // an array whose values are
          array => array[i])  // the subarray at that index
        )
        .join('')             // with its elements joined together
  );
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [` Oops.. You need map`(`(elt

Comment: Will this work correctly if `arrays[0]` is shorter than the other arrays?

Comment: No, but I don't know what the desired behavior is in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to do something like this:

```
myArray = [["s","m","a"],["d","f"],["t","h","r"]];

function generateStrings(array2d){
    newArray = [];

    function interate(n){
     newString = myArray.reduce((p,c)=>{return c[n]?p+c[n]:p},"")  
     console.log(newString)
     if (newString)newArray.push(newString),interate(n+1)
    }
    interate(0)

    return newArray;
}


generateStrings(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple reduce function to merge the Array.

```
const arr = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5] ];
const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, x) => [...acc, ...x], [])

console.log(newArr) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

If you need to create an `String` object after the merge you just have to apply `join('')` on the returned array.

#### With Concat

This is the `concat` version of the function in case you want to use it.

```
const newArr = arr.reduce((acc, x) => acc.concat(...x), [])
```

Comment: This is a very clumsy way to do `[].concat(...arr)`, which is not what the OP wants to do anyway.

Comment: Sure you can use concat too, but it wont look as good. Your choice.