# Iterate over multidimensional array, filter and create new one in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38918253/iterate-over-a-multidimensional-javascript-array-and-create-new-array) but it's not really what I'm looking for. I have a huge JSON file with this structure:

```
{
    foo: [1, 2, 3, ...],
    bar: [
        {
            name: 'abc',
            cl: 2,
            data: [
                      [[2, 4, 6], [4, 5, 6]],
                      [[5, 3, 5], [5, 7, 9]],
                      [[6, 8, 9], [6, 8, 9]],
                      ...
                  ]
        },
        {
            name: 'def',
            cl: 1,
            data: [10, 20, 30, ...]
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a class representing the object and I can extract the properties and the objects inside the parent object. The `foo` property is mandatory while the `bar` property is optional. `data` is a numeric array that can be 1D or 3D. The `foo.length` and the `data.length` are always the same. I want to reduce the file size (in term of contents) but keeping the same structure, i.e. copy the old object to a new  with exactly the same structure but shorter, so I could define a smaller length or range and get a new object, e.g. if I say to go from `foo[0]` to `foo[1]` then the data property will also go from `data[0]` to `data[1]` in the new object.

Is this possible? If yes, how can I achieve it? Maybe with `map`? but how?

```
function filter(obj, from, to){
     /// ?
}
```

Regards.

EDIT:

The new reduced object should be something like this:

```
{
    foo: [1, 2],
    bar: [
    {
        name: 'abc',
        cl: 2,
        data: [
                  [[2, 4, 6], [4, 5, 6]],
                  [[5, 3, 5], [5, 7, 9]]
              ]
    },
    {
        name: 'def',
        cl: 1,
        data: [10, 20]
    }
]
}
```

Comment: How exactly you want to reduce the file size?

Comment: please add some use cases.

Comment: I just edit the question.

Comment: What is the rule? Take the first two elements?

Comment: No, I should be able to take the elements from a point to another, so in this example, I want to go from `foo[0]` to `foo[1]`. But it could be any range inside the length of the `foo.length`. That will also affect the elements taken from `data`:

`foo.length = (bar with name 'abc').data.length = (bar with name 'def').data.length `

And `foo[i]` is related with `(bar with name 'abc').data[i]` and `(bar with name 'def').data[i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) for it.

```js
function slice(obj, from, to) {
    obj.foo = obj.foo.slice(from, to + 1);
    obj.bar.forEach(function (a) {
        a.data = a.data.slice(from, to + 1);
    });
}

var object = { foo: [1, 2, 3], bar: [{ name: 'abc', cl: 2, data: [[[2, 4, 6], [4, 5, 6]], [[5, 3, 5], [5, 7, 9]], [[6, 8, 9], [6, 8, 9]], ] }, { name: 'def', cl: 1, data: [10, 20, 30] }] };

slice(object, 0, 1);
console.log(object);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```